# Why am i getting this "E926" character on my dashboard?

Tags: fonts, unicode, dashboard

[image]

Why am i getting this `E926` in my Emacs dashboard and how can I fix this?

`dashboard` is an Emacs package - https://github.com/emacs-dashboard/emacs-dashboard.

Comment: Put your cursor on it and press `C-u C-x =`. It is most probably a character specified by a Unicode code point (probably 0xE926) but the font you are using does not provide a glyph for it, so it is an undisplayable character in that font. Emacs does its best to show you *something* about what it is supposed to be. Now the questions: what dashboard are you talking about? How do you get this dashboard? Please edit your question and add the details.

Comment: Dashboard is an Emacs package which is a startup screen that shows u stuff. I provided it's source above. BTW, thank you for helping. My font was indeed the issue.

Comment: So I take it you have solved your problem? If so, you might provide an answer of how you solved it (and you can even accept your own answer). That might help future visitors who might have a similar problem.

Comment: Yeah just gave the solution.

Comment: Instead of appending the solution to your question, you should make it into an answer: just cut and paste the solution to the answer box below (you might need to reformat some of the markup). In a couple of days, you will also be able to accept your answer which will mark the question as answered: that's the desired end result for *every* question. See the Tour and the Help Center when you click the `?` icon in the upper right to get more information about how the site operates.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for pointing me to the right directions. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution:**

You'll need the package "all-the-icons". Source-code: https://github.com/domtronn/all-the-icons.el

I use the 'use-package' declaration macro to install and manage my packages. Just install the package "all-the-icons" the way you usually install packages. This is my package config in my init.el if you're wondering: [image]

If you're using 'use-package', put the expression below in your init.el or wherever your configuration is sourced:

(use-package all-the-icons
:ensure t)

like this: [image]

After evaluating the above expression with either "eval-buffer" from anywhere in the configuration buffer or "C-x C-e" by the end of the expression, call the function "all-the-icons-install-fonts" just like "find-file" from "M-x" keybinding prompt. You'll get a prompt like this:
[image]

You might get (yes or no) instead of (y or n). Just confirm it accordingly. It will then download the required fonts and run the command "fc-cache -fv" on its own. Don't forget to save your config and run "eval-buffer" just to be sure and restart Emacs.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Instead of marking the original question as "(SOLVED)", go ahead and accept your own answer as soon as the system allows you to do so.

Comment: Okay, thank you!